# How to make the interface and all VS Code messages be in English?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code 1.70.3 (the maximum possible version for my HP 620 laptop (Windows 7 x64 Home Premium for Russia). I did not install the package for the Russian language. Installed the C# 1.25.4 extension (Microsoft). The VS Code interface is as it should be in English. But the messages and menu items of the C# extension are in Russian.

For example: a window with C# code is open. I bring the mouse cursor, for example, to the WriteLine. A window with a description of the method is shown, partly in English and partly in Russian. Another example: I place the cursor in a place in the code so that a light bulb appears. I press the light bulb. The menu items is in Russian.

**P.S.** .NET SDK 6.0.405

A search on the Internet showed that you need to delete the folder X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.omnisharp\x.x.x-net6.0\ru. **IT HELPED**. Next, I put a breakpoint in the code and start debugging. In the Run and Debug window, some of the inscriptions are in English, and some in Russian. Also in English and Russian there are messages in the DEBUG CONSOLE window. By analogy with the previous example, I delete the folder X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.debugger\ru and just in case also X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.razor\ru. **IT DIDN'T HELP**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I managed to solve the problem myself.

I deleted the ru.pak file from the folder X:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\locales.